# How to select three table with same column name but different values

Tags: mysql

Hi i'm so confused to select 3 table data value.

Ex:
In table1:

```
Id    value   price  <br> 
1     101     30   <br> 
2     102     40  <br>
3     103     50  <br>
```

In table 2

```
value       price   <br>
101       25  <br>
102       35   <br>
103       45  <br>
```

In table 3

```
value       Price   <br>
101          5%  <br>
102         6%   <br>
103         7%  <br>
```

in this how can i get all price value with id

I need a result like

```
ID    Price   Price   Price <br>
1  --   30  --   25 --     5%<br>
2  --    40  --   35   --   6%<br>
3  --    50  --   45   --   7%<br>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To format code, please prefix each line of code with 4 spaces. There is also a button to click that will do this, if you want to highlight and change many lines at a time. (Your table data could benefit from being formatted as code)

Answer (score 1):

Try with inner join

```
select id,table1.value, table1.price as price1,table2.price as price2,table3.price as price3 from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.value=table2.value
inner join table3 on table2.value=table3.value
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that aliases can be used too; one day the OP may want to join the same table into a query twice

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.id , table1.price , table2.price ,table3.price 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table.id = table2.id 
JOIN table3 ON table.value = table3.value
```

Result

Comment: table2 is joined  by value column  non by id

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.id,table1.value, table1.price,table2.price,table3.price
```

from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.value=table2.value
inner join table3 on table2.value=table3.value

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is perform a `JOIN` on your tables, using a coherent value known as *primary* and *foreign* key. The coherent values that links your tables together in this case is the column named *value*. So that's what you need to be using in your `JOIN`

```
SELECT
    table1.id as TABLE1_ID,
    table1.price as TABLE1_PRICE,
    table2.price as TABLE2_PRICE,
    table3.price as TABLE3_PRICE
FROM
  table1
LEFT JOIN
    table2 ON table1.`value` = table2.`value`
LEFT JOIN
    table3 ON table2.`value` = table3.`value`
```

Outputs:

[image]

[Working SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/689309/1)

More about `JOIN`'s [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Since you mentioned PHP in the comment section, try something like this:

```
$sql="SELECT
        table1.id as TABLE1_ID,
        table1.price as TABLE1_PRICE,
        table2.price as TABLE2_PRICE,
        table3.price as TABLE3_PRICE
    FROM
      table1
    LEFT JOIN
        table2 ON table1.`value` = table2.`value`
    LEFT JOIN
        table3 ON table2.`value` = table3.`value`"
$result_set=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($conn, $result_set);

$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result_set);
$count=0;

while($rowcount > $count) {
    $count++;

    echo 'id: '.$row['id'].'<br />';
    echo 'price: '.$row['price'].'<br />';

    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($conn, $result_set);
}
```

Remember to `include` your database connection file so that `$conn` is accessible.

If it doesn't work initially, try to swap out the actual column names with the defined aliases, like so:

`$row['id']` to `$row['TABLE1_ID']` etc.

Comment: Yeah i got your query. Thank you

Comment: and how to get the values in php ? Did you know?

Comment: @mohana try to see if the PHP in the updated answer works for you.

Comment: Yeah martin got it, that you so much

Comment: @mohana No problem, consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue. :)